# Yii2 kartik detailview hide label

Tags: yii2, label, detailview

If I'm doing `'label' => false`, it is still showing the empty cell of the label. Is it possible completely not to render label cell somehow? Many thanks!

UPDATE: `'labelColOptions' => ['hidden' => true]` works!

Comment: you want to hide label  or whole column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `visible` property :

For example,

```
[
   'attribute' => 'name',
   'value' => whatever,
   'visible' => (!empty($model->name)),
]
```

Comment: sorry, I would like to hide label only